Missing SOL Transfer to Phantom Wallet
On 2024-12-01 at 15:40, I transferred a certain amount of Solana from my Binance account to my Phantom wallet, but the funds have not appeared in my Phantom wallet yet. All payment details were correctly entered, and the transaction is marked as successful on both Binance and Solscan.
Please help me understand where my funds could have gone, as the transaction was completed successfully.
This is my transaction signature.49SJyicGG4pyDY48pAZW22RovxZzK2rNC4TXt54frTn1vxZark3aoA6FXriZMwtnDAVeaBDrXBJeQdMvwu44GWjG

Does anyone know how I can recover my Solana funds?

You couldn't have interacted with a malicous/drainer program because you still have tokens in your wallet and most importantly it's still owned by the System program.
Going through the tx's, it seems that you bridged the SOL into USDT in on EVM based chain on this tx -> 2TG9Qg3Bwnf1JUjhRu2q...
From the program logs, the funds were moved to this address -> 0x41eaD2756aDE4C2916462DcdBc1eeD7110aEBDe1

So how can I recover my SOL tokens now? Please provide detailed assistance.

It seems that you interacted with a malicious/drainer program.
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2TG9Qg3Bwnf1JUjhRu2qtShg1ZnGGinx1Rj3oQAbFJx54iPxxe72ZYsXUo5tm8Dtpz6TBH8qh1NU9cVviPvWd3UL

As you can see above transaction, there is another transaction is existed related to your account.
in that transaction, your sol is sent to below address you created.
5nraJyGTczB8X6zMuDzN5PEYKZwgGjjCmhMz7aE2y57E 

And then sol is sent to below address
8b9c7XAStj2dKpqk3U2SsXcxh5jPkuFTExUhnFZo4iFZ 


It seems that you interacted with a malicious/drainer program. What does this program mean? I have not interacted with any program, nor have I sent the Solana in my account to any wallet, as no Solana has ever appeared in my balance.

Do you know this address?
BrGihgGjCmpu2p96rou6GQj3sQpwgeud937jf4RvZP9G
Now your  wsol is sent to this address.

No, I do not recognize this address. I don't understand how it is possible for the coins to go to another wallet when I made the transaction correctly

It seems that your account is hacked

I need precise information. How are you finding and tracking these addresses to determine that my SOL is in another wallet?

https://solscan.io/tx/2TG9Qg3Bwnf1JUjhRu2qtShg1ZnGGinx1Rj3oQAbFJx54iPxxe72ZYsXUo5tm8Dtpz6TBH8qh1NU9cVviPvWd3UL
there you can find Transaction Actions  tag and there you can see detail info

https://solscan.io/account/ZfctMHBkZNTqeYGE47ekxtydgXgpo9xKJCAasjaCLTU
you can see the transactions list and there you can find what controlled this account.
thus, BrGihgGjCmpu2p96rou6GQj3sQpwgeud937jf4RvZP9G

Could you please tell me where you were going to swap SOL to USDT?

Actually, I want to keep my SOL balance, but I no longer trust Phantom. That’s why, as soon as my SOL is returned, I will transfer it either to another wallet or back to an exchange.

Also, when I check on Solscan using the transaction code, it shows that the coins are in my SOL wallet.

OFC, after finish first transaction you mentioned, coins in your phantom wallet.
But when you tried to exchange it, coins is sent to another wallet.

I have never seen those SOL tokens in my balance, let alone tried to exchange them. I still don’t understand how it’s possible that these SOL tokens never appeared in my balance. In your opinion, is there anything I can do now?

Sorry, I am not sure about that.
